# CSS div float. push last div up

Tags: css, css-float

I have 5 `<div>` elements and they all float left.

[image]

How can I push UP my last div? (i cant use 2 more wrappers because they will be re-sized with jQuery, all 5 of them must be in same wrapper)

[image]

I don't know if I explain my problem in a right way so if you have question, please ask.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="ModeliSadrzajAir">
    <div class="kocka220x140">1</div>
    <div class="kocka220x140">2</div>
    <div class="kocka220x300">3</div>
    <div class="kocka220x300">4</div>
    <div class="kocka460x140">5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#ModeliSadrzajAir {
    width: 960px;
    margin: -60px 0px 0px -10px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.kocka220x140 {
    border-radius:5px;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
.kocka220x300 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.kocka460x140 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 460px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that created the current thing? There's not really very much we can do without knowing what code you are using right now

Comment: can you change the order of the divs in your HTML markup?

Comment: [link to JSFiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/K3ANH/).

Comment: yes i can change order

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K3ANH/5/ this good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6NWv/1/)**

You've to set your `.kocka220x300`'s `float` property from `left` to `right`

I also suggest you to change your html to this

```
<div id="ModeliSadrzajAir">
    <div class="kocka220x140">1</div>
    <div class="kocka220x140">2</div>
    <div class="kocka220x300">4</div> <!-- This comes first  -->
    <div class="kocka220x300">3</div> <!-- This comes second -->
    <div class="kocka460x140">5</div>
</div>
```

This way, your **3** is on the left side of **4**, check the fiddle link for the update

Comment: this one is ok....for now. this isnt only divs. i mean i will reuse 220x300 so maybe i will need to change float right to left.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/czz2Z/9/

```
    .kocka460x140
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 460px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your example.

Basically I think you need one wrapper with `position:relative;` that contains all divs and make the 5th div `position:absolute`; and `bottom:0px;`. Also add `overflow:auto;` so that the max height you have contained in your parent div will push the parent div's height (read it again you will understand :P).

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/R8hJ3/1/

Comment: Usually it's really REALLY tricky to start designing layouts via `position`. It's better to use alternatives in almost every situation. Only in situations where you need absolutely positioned elements on the page (headers), or fixed elements (popups), you probably shouldn't use `position`, as a rule of thumb. Almost always there's better alternatives

Comment: I believe when you have an absolute element floating inside other element theres not really much problem. But yes if you an absolute element not in a container you will have a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have You Tried Some plugins like Grid-a-licious.. 
if not try it out.. Else if you need a pure Css you could have a look the link below..

> jsfiddle.net/chermanarun/HaV29/

Comment: That jsfiddle shows absolutely nothing like the original question. Until you edit your post to include an example that shows this question actually answered (which is what the 'answers' section is for: answering the original question), I downvoted your answer.

Comment: Cool Boss :) .. i just gave an idea for him not the exact answer.. to be very precise i haven't noticed your edited code..